# CUDA File missing, and how do I get it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I tried installing tensorflow, but when i try to test the code with PyCharm, i get following error message:

"Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found"

This is my code:

`import tensorflow
 import keras`

Are there any further questions?

Also, the complete output is this:

Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found

Using TensorFlow backend.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: That is the 64-bit cuda 10 run time, you need to install it, look for CUDA 10 runtime download using your favourite search engine

Comment: Did you install tensorflow and keras from within Anaconda?

Which python version do you use? My latest knowkledge is, that all the tensorflow stuff needs PYthon 3.6 instead of the latest one. (Maybe this change meanwhile. I still use a 3.6 based environment with all my Machine Learning stuff.)

Comment: yes i installed keras and tensorflow, and i don't get an error message. But i use Python 3.5

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica that's actually a terrible suggestion for someone using Conda. Conda should install those DLLs automatically and since environments are isolated, downloading it externally won't help.